# Promoting FOSS community events

Tags: discussion, advertising

Should we (at least temporarily, e.g. some days or weeks before they occurs) promote FOSS community events (e.g. https://fosdem.org/2021/schedule/track/geospatial/) somewhere on GIS Stack Exchange?

Comment: Could this be seen badly by only promoting  open source software when esri has also some (maybe free) meetings? If we go by the goal of the organisation (non-profit vs profit) then this seems like a good line. Also should more frequen events like QGIS monthly (now virtual) meetups? Or even events for smaller 'less popular' communities?

Comment: It should really be all free meetings or none.

Answer (score 5):

For an event which is only days or weeks away, or already running, you could advertise it in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

With a longer lead time the way to do it would be by taking advantage of Community Ads.

[Community Ads for 2021](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/community-ads-for-2021) is the latest request for candidate ads.

Comment: This is great - how do we promote this more? (ironically, how do we promote the Promotion ads page).....the number of votes and views of the page is really low, so Im thinking that not many know about this?

Comment: @nr_aus I think "the number of votes and views of the page is really low" is because participation on Meta is low.  To promote anything to do with our Main and Meta sites I think the best options are the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) (which currently has low participation too) and sharing to Twitter and/or Facebook (see sharing link below every post).